# How to place two bar charts beside each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

There are two tikz barcharts in this snippet. I'm able to display barcharts one after another but when i use subfigure/subfloat its giving an error

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \subfloat{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={$\mathcal{J}$ of WM},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={\footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper}
      %  legend pos=north west
    ]
     \legend{1\%, 5\%}
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,3,4,7,8,11}{\coordinate(l#1)at(axis cs:#1,0);}
    \end{axis}
    \coordinate(bbs)at(current bounding box.south);
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1)}] \text in {Axial,Coronial,Sagittarial} 
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]([xshift=8pt]l\s|-bbs)--node[below=5pt]{\text}([xshift=-8pt]l\e|-bbs);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }
    % A blank line here like a new paragraph so next picture is placed below
    \subfloat{
         \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={$\mathcal{J}$ of WM},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={\footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper}
      %  legend pos=north west
    ]
     \legend{1\%, 5\%}
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,3,4,7,8,11}{\coordinate(l#1)at(axis cs:#1,0);}
    \end{axis}
    \coordinate(bbs)at(current bounding box.south);
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1)}] \text in {Axial,Coronial,Sagittarial} 
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]([xshift=8pt]l\s|-bbs)--node[below=5pt]{\text}([xshift=-8pt]l\e|-bbs);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \caption{Accuracies Comparision}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question?

Comment: there are two tikz barcharts in this snippet. I'm able to display barcharts one after another but when  i used subfigure/subfloat its giving an error.(i need some thing like subcaption).

Comment: @NAV: It's better to add that explanation to the question itself than using a comment

Comment: You have not loaded the `subfig` package which provides the `\subfloat` command.

Comment: I'd just put them inside `\begin{tabular}{c}...\end{tabular}`. Judging from your examples, you want them on TOP of each other rather than BESIDE each other -- as they are too big to go side-by-side.

Comment: @Andrew: Though in current form the graphs are too big to stay side by side, it is always possible to perform a scaling :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Sure, but them I'd need even bigger glasses:) Or a glass of something!

Comment: @Andrew: Sometimes I find in some papers graphs totally unreadable. And there's no hope for them. However, by setting a good resolution in your PDF reader, if the graphs are done with TikZ, you can always scale the page to have the information readable.

Comment: @Andrew do you have any better idea instead of graphs in papers??

Comment: @NAV I'm not sure what you mean by "instead of graphs". Is this a typo? If it's not a typo then perhaps my attempts at humour above misfired. Graphs are certainly very useful in many contexts and I apologise if you have interpreted my comments as saying something else.

Answer (score 5):

You have missed a parentheses (2 places) in

```
\foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1)) %<-- this one, you have only one of them.
```

You forgot to load the `subfig` package which provides `\subfloat`command. Having said that, you can use the standard method of `\resizebox`:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[][Sub figure first]{\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={$\mathcal{J}$ of WM},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={\footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper}
      %  legend pos=north west
    ]
     \legend{1\%, 5\%}
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,3,4,7,8,11}{\coordinate(l#1)at(axis cs:#1,0);}
    \end{axis}
    \coordinate(bbs)at(current bounding box.south);
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1))}] \text in {Axial,Coronial,Sagittarial}
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]([xshift=8pt]l\s|-bbs)--node[below=5pt]{\text}([xshift=-8pt]l\e|-bbs);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }}
    % A blank line here like a new paragraph so next picture is placed below
    \subfloat[][Sub figure second]{\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
         \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={$\mathcal{J}$ of WM},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={\footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          \footnotesize
          wells\\\footnotesize lemput\\\footnotesize wang\\\footnotesize proposed\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper}
      %  legend pos=north west
    ]
     \legend{1\%, 5\%}
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,3,4,7,8,11}{\coordinate(l#1)at(axis cs:#1,0);}
    \end{axis}
    \coordinate(bbs)at(current bounding box.south);
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1))}] \text in {Axial,Coronial,Sagittarial}
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]([xshift=8pt]l\s|-bbs)--node[below=5pt]{\text}([xshift=-8pt]l\e|-bbs);
\end{tikzpicture}
    }}
    \caption{Accuracies Comparision}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]